# How to compare database data in php

Tags: php, sql, compare, mariadb

I want to compare the database data in the php.

This is my table

hospital_payment_data table

```
  id      | date  |     cash_amount_received
----------------------------------
  1        2020-04-01      7000
  2        2020-04-29      1000
  3        2020-04-29      2000
  4        2020-04-29      3000
  5        2020-04-29      4000
  6        2020-04-29      5000
  7        2020-04-29      6000
  8        2020-04-29      70000
```

cash_receipt_publish table

```
  id      |    date  |    amount
----------------------------------
  1             2020-04-29       1000
  2             2020-04-29       2000
  3             2020-04-29       3000
  4             2020-04-29       4000
  5             2020-04-29       5000
  6             2020-04-29       5000
  7             2020-04-29       7000
```

This is my sql syntax

```
    SELECT ifnull(hospital_payment_data.id,'-') AS pg_id, 
ifnull(hospital_payment_data.date,'-') AS pg_date, 
ifnull(hospital_payment_data.cash_amount_received,'-') AS pg_amount, 
ifnull(cash_receipt_publish.id,'-') AS van_id, 
ifnull(cash_receipt_publish.date,'-') AS van_date, 
ifnull(cash_receipt_publish.amount,'-') AS van_amount
FROM hospital_payment_data
LEFT JOIN cash_receipt_publish ON hospital_payment_data.id = cash_receipt_publish.id
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ifnull(hospital_payment_data.id,'-') AS pg_id, ifnull(hospital_payment_data.date,'-') AS pg_date, ifnull(hospital_payment_data.cash_amount_received,'-') AS pg_amount, 
            ifnull(cash_receipt_publish.id,'-') AS van_id, ifnull(cash_receipt_publish.date,'-') AS van_date, ifnull(cash_receipt_publish.amount,'-') AS van_amount
            FROM hospital_payment_data
            RIGHT JOIN cash_receipt_publish ON hospital_payment_data.id = cash_receipt_publish.id
            WHERE hospital_payment_data.id IS NULL limit 0
```

in this web page result

[image]

I Want result

> If the date and the amount match or the amount match, I would like to
>   express it as False by comparing the table with the table in
>   cash_receipt_public.

```
id     |  cash_amount_received    |    amount|    result
-----------------------------------------------------
  1          7000                    7000          true
  2          1000                    1000          true
  3          2000                    2000          true
  4          3000                    3000          true
  5          4000                    4000          true
  6          5000                    5000          true
  7          6000                    null          false
  8          10000                   null          false
  9          null                    5000          false
```

Comment: Where do the "id"s come from?  They don't make sense.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a `full join`;

```
select coalesce(hpd.cash_amount_received, cpr.amount),
       coalesce(hpd.date, cpr.date),
       (case when hpd.id is not null and crp.id is not null then 'true' else 'false' end)
from (select hpd.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by date, cash_amount_received order by id) as seqnum
      from hospital_payment_data hpd
     ) hpd full join
     (select crp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date, amount order by id) as seqnum
      from cash_receipt_publish crp
     ) crp
     on hpd.date = crp.date and
        hpd.cash_amount_received = crp.amount and
        hpd.seqnum = crp.seqnum;
```

EDIT:

In MariaDB, you can use:

```
select amount, min(date),
       (count(*) = 2)
from ((select hpd.date, cash_amount_received as amount,
              row_number() over (partition by cash_amount_received order by id) as seqnum
       from hospital_payment_data hpd
      )  union all
      (select crp.date, amount,
              row_number() over (partition by amount order by id) as seqnum
       from cash_receipt_publish crp
      )
     ) x
group by amount, seqnum
```

Comment: @전준휘 . . . You should tag the question with the database.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a genius.
But one condition is lacking.
True should be used even if the dates are different and the amount is correct. But it appears as False. What should I do?

Comment: The result came out as I wanted. Thank you